# Set up c# language server (omnisharp) for neovim to develop app with .NET Core 5.0.17

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, mono, omnisharp

I been battling to set up a C# language server (omnisharp) for neovim. The main problem is that I gotta use .NET Core 5.0.17 and omnisharp no longer ships with mono and MSBuild tools (mentioned in omnisharp-vscode repo [announcement section](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode#announcements)).

When I try to edit a .cs file I get the message "Client 1 quit with exist code 150 and signal 0". When I check `lsp.log` I get `"[ERROR][2022-07-20 13:09:08] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:420   "rpc"   "dotnet"    "stderr"    "You must install or update .NET to run this application.\n\nApp: /home/josh/.local/share/nvim/lsp_servers/omnisharp/omnisharp/OmniSharp.dll\nArchitecture: x64\nFramework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0-preview.7.21317.1' (x64)\n.NET location: /opt/dotnet/\n\nThe following frameworks were found:\n  5.0.17 at [/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]\n\nLearn about framework resolution:\nhttps://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed\n\nTo install missing framework, download:\nhttps://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0-preview.7.21317.1&arch=x64&rid=manjaro-x64\n"`

In order to make Omnisharp work with .NET versions below 6.0 I have to do the following:

1. Set `useModernNet = false` (mentioned in omnisharp-vscode repo [requirement section](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode#requirements))
2. Install [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/download/preview/) (mentioned in omnisharp-vscode repo [requirement section](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode#requirements)).
3. Due to my distro (manjaro) I also have to install [mono-msbuild](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/mono-msbuild/) (mentioned in omnisharp-roslyn [introduction secction](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn#introduction))

In order to tackle the first one I generate a `lsp/settings/omnisharp.lua` file for lsp installer to setup the cmp and to set `useModernNet = false` following instructions from [lsp config repo](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#omnisharp). I add such file to `lsp/lsp-installer.lua` which is then called by `lsp/init.lua`.

Hopefully someone can lead me to the solution or right direction to it. Thanks for even taking the time to read.

My neovim setup is [here](https://github.com/josh-hdz/neovim-config) (credit to [chris@machine](https://github.com/ChristianChiarulli) for the setup found [here](https://github.com/LunarVim/Neovim-from-scratch))

**nvim/lua/user/lsp/lsp-installer.lua**

```
local status_ok, lsp_installer = pcall(require, "nvim-lsp-installer")
if not status_ok then
    return
end

-- Register a handler that will be called for all installed servers.
-- Alternatively, you may also register handlers on specific server instances instead (see example below).
lsp_installer.on_server_ready(function(server)
    local opts = {
        on_attach = require("user.lsp.handlers").on_attach,
        capabilities = require("user.lsp.handlers").capabilities,
    }

     if server.name == "jsonls" then
        local jsonls_opts = require("user.lsp.settings.jsonls")
        opts = vim.tbl_deep_extend("force", jsonls_opts, opts)
     end

   if server.name == "sumneko_lua" then
        local sumneko_opts = require("user.lsp.settings.sumneko_lua")
        opts = vim.tbl_deep_extend("force", sumneko_opts, opts)
     end
--------------------------------ADDED CODE--------------------------------    
   if server.name == "omnisharp" then
    local omnisharp_opts = require("user.lsp.settings.omnisharp")
        opts = vim.tbl_deep_extend("force", omnisharp_opts, opts)
   end
--------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    -- This setup() function is exactly the same as lspconfig's setup function.
    -- Refer to https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md
    server:setup(opts)
end)
```

**nvim/lua/user/lsp/settings/omnisharp.lua**

```
local pid = vim.fn.getpid()
local omnisharp_bin = "/home/josh/.local/share/nvim/lsp_servers/omnisharp/omnisharp/OmniSharp.dll"

return {
  cmd = { omnisharp_bin, "--languageserver" , "--hostPID", tostring(pid) },
  omnisharp = {
    useModernNet = false,
    monoPath = "/usr/bin/mono"
  }
}
```

### Tech stack

System (cat /etc/lsb-release)

```
DISTRIB_ID=ManjaroLinux
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.3.1
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Ruah
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux"
```

.NET (dotnet --info)

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.408
 Commit:    da985e2a23

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     manjaro
 OS Version:
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /opt/dotnet/sdk/5.0.408/

global.json file:
  /home/josh/storage/Documents/csharp/global.json

Host:
  Version:      6.0.7
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       0ec02c8c96

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.408 [/opt/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

Neovim (nvim --version)

```
NVIM v0.7.0
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by builduser

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

Mono (mono --version)

```
Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0 (makepkg/ed0788bf61f Sun Apr 24 04:25:18 PM UTC 2022)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug
    Interpreter:   yes
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    Suspend:       hybrid
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

MSBuild (msbuild -version)

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.10.1 for Mono
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

16.10.1.15601%
```

Comment: I been able to attach the server language with `use_mono = true` at omnisharp.lua

Answer (score 3):

I know I am late to the party ;-)

I recommend using csharp-ls (https://www.nuget.org/packages/csharp-ls/). Omnisharp is outdated.
I use it with Conquer of Completion (https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim)

My `coc-setting.json` looks like:

```
{
  "suggest.noselect": false,
  "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": [
      "csharp",
    "sql",
    "javascript",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact",
    "json",
    "javasciptreact",
    "typescript.tsx",
    "graphql"
  ],
  "languageserver": {
    "csharp": {
      "command": "csharp-ls",
      "rootPatterns": [
        "*.sln",
        "git"
      ],
      "filetypes": ["cs", "csharp"]
    },
    "haskell": {
      "command": "haskell-language-server-wrapper",
      "args": ["--lsp"],
      "rootPatterns": [
        ".stack.yaml",
        ".hie-bios",
        "BUILD.bazel",
        "cabal.config",
        "package.yaml"
      ],
      "filetypes": ["hs", "lhs", "haskell"]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am using two custom language servers.
The object `languageserver.csharp` object should be relevant only for the completion.